# Decimal quantity products price

Tags: magento2, quantity

We are selling fabrics, I want the quantity to be by meter price, like decimal numbers.
 For example a client can order 0.1 m; 0.2m ; 0.3m; 0.4m; 0.5m etc.. If the client orders 0.15m it will transform automatically to 0.2m.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

> Catalog > Product > Advanced Inventory

Change value of **Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart** this Option in **Decimal Points** [For ex 0.25] or anything minimum quantity you want to add into cart.

Comment: thanks for your answer but how to round off the value from 0.15 to 2

Comment: you can use event add_to_cart_after and add  round qty logic in observer